# Removing elements from embedded array by matching with different array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have an embedded array of tweets in my Mongodb and with every tweet comes a tweetID (not to be confused with the mongodb assigned id).

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "54d95cb062917897ad26c5e5"
},
"name": "foo",
"tweets": [
    {
        "tweetID": "1234",
        "text": "bla bla bla"
    },
    {
        "tweetID": "4321",
        "text": "bla bla bla",
    }

... and so on
```

Now in my app I have another array full of tweetID's that should be deleted.

```
var tweetsToBeDeleted = [ "1234", "4321" ];
```

And i am trying to get mongoose to do so with:

```
ChannelsModel.update( { },
                      { $pull: { tweets: { $elemMatch: { tweetID: tweetsToBeDeleted } } } },
                      { multi: true },
                      function ( err ) {
                         console.log( "err - " + err );
                      } 
);
```

But when i try to run this, nothing gets deleted. The error callback will executed but `err` is `null`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) when matching a field to multiple values:

```
var tweetsToBeDeleted = [ "1234", "4321" ];
ChannelsModel.update( { },
                      { $pull: { tweets: { tweetID: { $in: tweetsToBeDeleted } } } },
                      { multi: true },
                      function ( err ) {
                         console.log( "err - " + err );
                      } 
);
```